# mysql strange characters iphone and safari

Tags: iphone

 hello 

Some messages (like the one above) are saved in my mysql database and then when i retrieve the data yellow hearts are shown at the start and the end of the message in the mobile iphone safari browser!

Why is this happening? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

That generally happens when you've got a charset issue.  Some code might be helpful if you need a more explicit answer.

Character's aren't some magic item that your computer stores, they're a collection of bits -- 1's and 0's.  They are then mapped to characters, so that 0052 becomes 'a', 0053 becomes 'b', and so on.  (Made up numbers)  If your charset is wrong, what's happening is that the bits that represent something in one program (curly quotes are a common culprit in HTML) don't have an appropriate match in another.